# Client certificates iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, linker

I'm trying to extract a .p12 file and use it for a two way authentication against my own server. when i'm trying to compile i get some linking errors. The errors are refering to:

- _kSecImportExportPassphrase
- _SecIdentityCopyCertificate
- _kSecImportItemTrust
- _SecPKCS12Import
- _kSecImportItemIdentity

Here is the code i'm using to extract the p12 file:

```
        -(void)clientCert   
        {
            NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"torbix" ofType:@"p12"];
            NSData *p12data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
            CFDataRef inP12data = (CFDataRef)p12data;

            SecIdentityRef myIdentity;
            SecTrustRef myTrust;
            OSStatus status = extractIdentityAndTrust(inP12data, &myIdentity, &myTrust);

            SecCertificateRef myCertificate;
            SecIdentityCopyCertificate(myIdentity, &myCertificate);
            const void *certs[] = { myCertificate };
            CFArrayRef certsArray = CFArrayCreate(NULL, certs, 1, NULL);

        }
        OSStatus extractIdentityAndTrust(CFDataRef inP12data, SecIdentityRef *identity, SecTrustRef *trust)
        {
            OSStatus securityError = errSecSuccess;

            CFStringRef password = CFSTR("password");
            const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
            const void *values[] = { password };

            CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);

            CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
            securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inP12data, options, &items);

            if (securityError == 0) {
                CFDictionaryRef myIdentityAndTrust = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
                const void *tempIdentity = NULL;
                tempIdentity = CFDictionaryGetValue(myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemIdentity);
                *identity = (SecIdentityRef)tempIdentity;
                const void *tempTrust = NULL;
                tempTrust = CFDictionaryGetValue(myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemTrust);
                *trust = (SecTrustRef)tempTrust;
            }

            if (options) {
                CFRelease(options);
            }

        return securityError;
    }
```

Why do i get these errors?

Comment: What are the errors and what frameworks are you linking to?

Comment: Will check it out more tomorrow when i'm back in the lab! :)

Comment: It's solved now! The solution is in the answer! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the `Security.framework` to your project.

In Xcode 4.2+ in the target go to the "Build Phases" tab, "Link BinariesWith Libraries", Click the "+" and add the "Security.framework".

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Will try it tomorrow when i get back to the lab. (Y)